# CSS formatting of radiobuttons

Tags: css

Given the following HTML fragment:

```
<span name="foo" class="foo-class">
   <input name="foo" value="0" id="foo2_0" type="radio">
   <label for="foo2_0">The Server Side</label>
   <input name="foo" value="1" id="foo2_1" type="radio">
   <label for="foo2_1">Java Lobby</label>
   <input name="foo" value="2" id="foo2_2" type="radio">
   <label for="foo2_2">Java.Net</label>
</span>

<span name="bar" class="bar-class">
   <input name="bar" value="0" id="bar2_0" type="radio">
   <label for="bar2_0">The Server Side</label>
   <input name="bar" value="1" id="bar2_1" type="radio">
   <label for="bar2_1">Java Lobby</label>
   <input name="bar" value="2" id="bar2_2" type="radio">
   <label for="bar2_2">Java.Net</label>
</span>
```

Is there CSS that will layout the radiochoices in foo horizontally:

The Server Side
   
   Java Lobby
   
   Java.Net

And the radiochoices in bar vertically, as if they had been separated with `<br/>`?

The Server Side
   
   Java Lobby
   
   Java.Net

Or do you need to add css class attributes to the radiobuttons, or  to the labels, or both?

On edit: this is generated code, so while the span tags can be changed to whatever you wish, the *only possible changes to the tags inside the spans (the input and label tags)* is the addition of css classes to the inputs and labels. (If I wanted easy, I'd have wrapped each radiochoice in an `<li>...</li>`. Unfortunately, I have to work with what I've got.)

Note: a perfectly acceptable answer is, "this can't be (portably) done, find a better way to generate the code, buddy", though if that's the answer, give me some idea of why.

---

Ah, excellent! Not only does jdangel's solution work, it works if I assign the same CSS to divs enclosing the spans. Thank you jdangel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED BASED ON FEEDBACK: That sucks. Try:

```
.bar-class label {display:block; margin-left: 30px;clear:right;}
.bar-class input {float:left;clear:left;}
```